# Vim: `cd` to path stored in variable

Tags: vim

I'm pretty new to vim, and I'm having a hard time understanding some subtleties with vim scripting. Specifically, I'm having trouble working with commands that expect an unquoted-string (is there a name for this?). For example

```
cd some/unquoted/string/path
```

The problem is that I'd like to pass a variable, but calling

```
let pathname = 'some/path'
cd pathname
```

will try to change the current directory to 'pathname' instead of 'some/path'. One way around this is to use

```
let cmd = 'cd ' . pathname
execute cmd
```

but this seems a bit roundabout. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112842/vim-command-after-cd/2112919#2112919) actually uses `cd` with a variable, but it doesn't work on my system ("a:path" is treated as the path as described above).

I'm using `cd` as a specific example, but this behavior isn't unique to `cd`; for example, the `edit` command also behaves this way. (Is there a name for this type of command?)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**TL;DR**: use `execute 'cd' fnameescape(pathname)`

**Explanation**: Lots of basic commands that take filenames as an argument support backtick syntax:

```
command `shell command`
```

or

```
command `=vim_expression`
```

so your example may be written as

```
cd `=pathname`
```

if you are running this in a controlled environment. You **must not use this variant in plugins** because a) there is `&wildignore` setting that may step in your way: `set wildignore=*|cd =pathname` will make `cd` fail regardless of what is stored in the `pathname` and b) if pathname contains newlines it will be split into two or more directories. Thus what you should use for any piece of code you intend to share is

```
execute 'cd' fnameescape(pathname)
```

Note that you must not use `execute "cd" pathname` because it does not care about special characters in pathname (for example, space).

Answer (score 6):

The basic commands in Vim never do any processing of variables (how would it know that you didn't mean to change to the pathname directory instead of the some/path one?).  You don't have to be quite as roundabout as you suggested, you can just do:

```
exe 'cd' pathname
```

Note that `exe` concatenates arguments with a space automatically, so you *don't* have to do:

```
exe 'cd ' . pathname
```

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed cleaner. Is there a list of these "basic commands"?

Answer (score 0):

A lot time ago I wrote this [plugin (function `FixPathName()`](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/downloads/detail?name=system_tools-2.1.0.vba&can=2&q=#makechanges) in order to solve this kind of issues. Now vim has some new functions like `shellescape()` when the path need to be used with external commands.